# Issue with Okta Toolhar and OktaBHO loading in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, okta

I am having an issue installing the plug-in for SWA for IE 11.  Although the plug-in appears to install, when the browser is restarted and the user logs in it appears that the plugin is not installed and wants to repeat the process.  When you look at Manage Add-ons, it shows two Okta add-ons (Okta toolbar and OktaBHO Class), both of which are enabled.

Has anyone encountered this?

How has this been resolved?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that you have a group policy in place that is preventing 3rd party browser extensions from running.

The Group policy options that would cause this is:

```
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Internet Control Panel\Advanced Page\Allow third-party browser extensions
```

The results of the GPO setting on a client system would be a registry entry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"EnableAutoUpgrade"=dword:00000000
"Enable Browser Extensions"="no"
```

From a resolution perspective, remove the offending GPO. Chances are it was put in place for a reason and it is an On or Off setting, no granularity.

There is an alternative means of enabling and disabling browser extensions with granularity available:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn454941.aspx

It comes with it's own set of difficulties so you'll want to do your homework before you jump in.

-Matt